# HABTM association not saved - cakephp

Tags: cakephp, save, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've been searching for all types of solutions and it's not working. I have two models, Bredbook and Genre, in bredbook.php and genre.php, associated with HABTM. No way to save the association.

Here is the code of one model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Bredbook' => array('className' => 'Bredbook',
'joinTable' => 'bredbooks_genres',
'foreignKey' => 'genre_id',
'associationForeignKey' => 'bredbook_id'));
```

Here is the form:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Bredbook', array('action' => 'firstConnection'));
echo $this->Form->input('Genre', array('options' => $genres, 'empty' => false));
echo $this->Form->end('Validate');
```

And in BredbooksController.php:

```
if ($this->request->data)
{
    if($this->Bredbook->saveAssociated($this->request->data))
        return $this->redirect('/bredbooks/index');
}
```

The creation of the bredbook is ok, but no association is created in the table bredbooks_genres. I've tried everything... any help will be welcome.

Comment: Add a debug($this->request->data) right before the save and let us know the result

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this line and I have set the debug to 2, but I don't know where it should be printed...

Comment: Never mind, I stupidly kept the redirection... here is the array: array(
 'Bredbook' => array(
  'Genre' => '3'
 )
)

Comment: Based on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm , I think your array should look like this: `array('Bredbook' => array(), 'Genre' => array('id' => 3))` , but I am not positive.

Comment: I tried this too just after posting the debug here. I tried with just the Genre id, with the whole object, and at different levels (same as 'Bredbook', inside 'Bredbook', etc. I'm trying several functions too (save, saveAssociated...) because I'm not sure which one I need to use... I've been stuck for days now.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Just explained in a comment the case when you're creating a new record. Let me now if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it: I don't know if it's a necessary thing, but I just used cake bake to generate everything: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html

Now I need some work to rearrange all the views, but my saving is working, with the exact same code I posted first, and I think I saved some time too with all that generated behaviour I needed !

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `Bredbook.id` in your data array:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Bredbook');
//It can be any other attribute, but need some Breedbook data
echo $this->Form->input('Bredbook.id', array('value' => $id));
echo $this->Form->input(
    'Genre', 
     array(
        'options' =>$genres, 
        'empty' => false
    )
);
echo $this->Form->end('Validate');
```

Or make sure your `$this->request->data` looks similar to this before saving:

```
Array
(
    [Bredbook] => Array
    (
         //It can be any other attribute, but need some Breedbook data
        [id] => 1
    )

    [Genre] => Array
    (
        [Genre] => Array
        (
             [0] => 1
        )

    )
)
```

This Solution will work also work when you are creating a new `Bredbook` as long as you send some data of that Model, it doesn't need to be the `id`, you can also send name or other attributes from your `Bredbook` Model. If you send `Bredbook.id` it will not create a new record and only make the associations, but if you don't send the `id` and send other attributes (like `name` for example) it will create a new record and will associate it with the `Genre` data your are sending.

Comment: `array(
 'Bredbook' => array(
  'Genre' => '3'
 ),
 'Genre' => array(
  'Genre' => array(
   (int) 0 => '3'
  )
 )
)`, it doesn't work either. I tried everything, no association created

Comment: You need to put an attribute of the brebook model inside the breebok array for it to work. Can you paste how does your breadbooks table looks like?

Comment: Oh sorry, I do. It's just that I pasted just the field related to the Genre, but I enter other informations. I have that : `array( 'Bredbook' => array( 'Genre' => '3', 'name' => 'New name', etc... ), 'Genre' => array( 'Genre' => array( (int) 0 => '3' ) ) )`. I wonder if the problem can be elsewhere. I have the 3 tables with the correct foreign keys, I have two models... should I have a model for the association table ? Should I have some special fields in them ?

Comment: have you tried sending the data without the `'Genre'` key ? something like this `array( 'Bredbook' => array( 'name' => 'New name', etc... ), 'Genre' => array( 'Genre' => array( (int) 0 => '3' ) ) )` i think that should do it. You only need two models, the third is just the join table.

Comment: I will try as soon as I can, but at the moment I can't even access to localhost/xampp... I tried testing other frameworks without deleting the cakephp project, but now it doesn't work anymore. I will let you know if I finally succeed

Comment: With exactly the array you recommend (I used unset() on the Genre id of Bredbook) it doesn't work either. I also tested to save a bredbook, then save it again with its id and the association. It doesn't work